# How can I align a shield with a character's back (dynamically) in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, vertex, fbx

**QUESTION:**

I currently load 2 FBX files in three.js: a character/knight and a shield.

I can dynamically change which knight-shield combination is loaded.

I have been googling for a while now and was unable to find how I could align dynamically the shield with the character's back.

That is, if I change the character/knight but keep the same shied, how can I re-align the shield to the new character/knight's back ?

I am not even sure how to properly formulate my question in three.js terms, but I would say I am trying to make sure the outermost vertex of the character on the Z axis must be almost in contact with the central vertex (that is, the middle point of the back of the shield must be at a certain distance to the back of the character/knight and should align with the centre of the upper body of the character/knight) of the back of the shield.

Here is my current code:

---

**CODE:**

```
if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

var container, stats, controls;
var camera, scene, renderer, light;

var clock = new THREE.Clock();

var mixers = [];

var myObject;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
    camera.position.set( 100, 200, 300 );
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
    controls.target.set( 0, 100, 0 );
    controls.update();

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xa0a0a0 );
    scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xa0a0a0, 200, 1000 );

    light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x444444 );
    light.position.set( 0, 200, 0 );
    scene.add( light );

    light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    light.position.set( 0, 200, 100 );
    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadow.camera.top = 180;
    light.shadow.camera.bottom = -100;
    light.shadow.camera.left = -120;
    light.shadow.camera.right = 120;
    scene.add( light );

    light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    light.position.set( 0, 0, -50 );
    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadow.camera.top = 180;
    light.shadow.camera.bottom = -100;
    light.shadow.camera.left = -120;
    light.shadow.camera.right = 120;
    scene.add( light );

    // ground
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2000, 2000 ), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x999999, depthWrite: false } ) );
    mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add( mesh );

    var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 2000, 20, 0x000000, 0x000000 );
    grid.material.opacity = 0.2;
    grid.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add( grid );

    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++ ) {

        load(names[i]);

    }

    function load(name) {

        var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader(manager);
        loader.load( '../pathToFile/'+name+'.FBX', function ( object ) {

            object.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );
            mixers.push( object.mixer );

            object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                if ( child.isMesh ) {

                    child.castShadow = true;
                    child.receiveShadow = true;
                }

            } );   

            scene.add( object );

           // Saving the shield inside myObject so I can modify its position later

            if (name.includes("shield")) {
                myObject = object;
            }

        } );
    }

    // model

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    // stats
    stats = new Stats();
    container.appendChild( stats.dom );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    if ( mixers.length > 0 ) {

        for ( var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i ++ ) {

            mixers[ i ].update( clock.getDelta() );

        }

    }

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

    stats.update();

    // My attempt at changing the position of the shield, as you can see, values are hardcoded in, I don't know how to dynamically put the shield where it should be dependent on the first object that is loaded: the character/knight

    myObject.position.set(0,132,-15);

}
```

Comment: This might be very difficult unless your character model has a specific "back" or "torso" group or mesh. With a back/torso, you could simply add the shield to that group/mesh to parent it, and adjust the transformations accordingly. If you _don't_ have this kind of structure, you could potentially identify the boning which controls the torso/back, and see if you can make your shield follow that as well. As a last resort, you could identify vertices on the back, calculate an orientation from those, and apply that orientation to the shield.

Comment: @TheJim01 "As a last resort, you could identify vertices on the back, calculate an orientation from those, and apply that orientation to the shield." That would be a potential solution since some models have no bones. How can I "identify" vertices on the back ?

Comment: You won't like this, and it's why this is a last resort: _manually_. There is no magic way of detecting a vertex's context. You'll need to figure out a way to identify where on the model a vertex exists. You could use tools like `Points` and `Raycaster` to help, but that's bond the scope of this question.

Comment: @TheJim01 I'll rather try my luck with Raycaster than do it manually ! Thank you for answering :)